# How Do I Specify The Distro For Azure App Service Plan?

Tags: azure

I am creating an App Service Plan in Azure but when I create it I get the options:

> Operating System: Linux Windows

Similarly, if I [create it with Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_plan#argument-reference) the options are

> kind - (Optional) The kind of the App Service Plan to create. Possible values are Windows, Linux, elastic (for Premium Consumption)

When I check on the app I created I see:

```
/home# uname -a
Linux 5.4.0-1031-azure #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 10:03:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The security team from our client is being quite particular about distros. We would have to submit an exception if any of our stack is not running on RHEL.

How/Can do I specify the distro for the Azure App Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App Service is a managed service by Azure. You can only specify if you want to run your applications on Windows / Linux, not you can specify a particular version (for Windows) or distro for Linux.

The closest, would be to run Containers on App Service and make your images based on the Linux distro you want. (e.g. ubuntu, alpine, etc)